# publishing asp.net mvc application results in jnlp error

Tags: asp.net, applet

I have a java applet that runs on a particular webpage of an asp.net mvc 2 project (visual studio 2008). The java applet is run using LiveConnect etc from java. This requires a jnlp file. All of my jars and jnlp files are in the root directory of the application.

When I run the web site via visual studio's built-in server, everything is fine. When I publish the website and run it in IIS Express, I get this error in the java console:

> exception: JNLP file error: /test-applet.jnlp. Please make sure the
>   file exists and check if "codebase" and "href" in the JNLP file are
>   correct..

Any ideas?

Comment: answer: needed to add this to application config:    <mimeMap fileExtension=".jnlp" mimeType="x-java-jnlp-file" />

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure IIS is configured to serve .jnlp files?
do you have a catch-all StaticFileHandler defined in web.config?

you might just want to add a StaticFileHandler to serve .jnlp files, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bya7fh0a.aspx

Comment: No I don't. I will try this and mark your answer correct if it works. Thank you very much.